# Comparing two date/time fields to see if they occurred within 60 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset like this

```
Member   Open_date     Mort_Close_date  Share_type
1        6/1/2020                          1
1                       5/5/2020           2
1        9/15/2020                         3
```

I'm trying to write either a case statement or an iif statement that Counts the number of Accounts opened (Open_Date) within 60 days after they close on a mortgage (Mort_Close_date). So in the example above, it bring back a count of 1, because only the third one was opened more than 60 days later. The problem is I don't feel this code is anywhere close. Even if the below code worked, it doesn't, how would I only compare the open_date, mort_close_date when the member matches?

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, S.Open_Date,  MC_LOAN_DATE) <= 60, THEN 'Open New Account within 60 days'
ELSE 'No Accounts Opened') END AS NewAccountsOpened
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select count(*)
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.member = t.member and
                    t2.open_date >= t.mort_close_date and
                    t2.open_date < dateadd(day, 60, mort_close_date)
             );
```